# Retrieving values from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list of consumers:

```
API_CONSUMERS = [{'name': 'localhost',
                  'host': '127.0.0.1:5000',
                  'api_key': 'Ahth2ea5Ohngoop5'},
                 {'name': 'localhost2',
                  'host': '127.0.0.1:5001',
                  'api_key': 'Ahth2ea5Ohngoop6'}]
```

And I have a host variable:

```
host = '127.0.0.1:5000'
```

I want to:

1. Check if host is in the values in the list of API_CONSUMERS, then
2. If the host exists retrieve the `api_key` to use elsewhere.

Originally I was checking the host values like this:

```
if not any(consumer['host'] == host for consumer in API_CONSUMERS):
    #do something
```

But then realised to retrieve the `api_key` I would have to loop through each consumer anyway, so might as well combine the two:

```
for consumer_info in API_CONSUMERS:
    if consumer_info['host'] == host:
        consumer = consumer_info
if not consumer:
    #do something
```

What is the best way to do this?  I feel like what I'm doing isn't "pythonic".

**Solution**

```
try:
    api_key = next(d['api_key'] for d in consumers if d['host'] == host)
except StopIteration:
    #do something
```

Comment: Is the host value always unique?  If so maybe a dictionary of dictionaries is a better data type with host as the key.

Comment: Yes, the host value is always unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> next(consumer['api_key'] for consumer in API_CONSUMERS if consumer['host'] == host)
'Ahth2ea5Ohngoop5'
```

Don't forget to catch the exception that will be raised if the value is not found.

Answer (score 3):

```
api_key = next(d['api_key'] for d in API_CONSUMERS if d['host'] == host)
```

Will get the key in one go, and will raise an exception if there is no such host in the list.

**EDIT**

As sr2222 pointed out, the semantics of the OP's code and mine are different if the hosts aren't unique. So to get the last host, one can do something like this:

```
api_key = [d['api_key'] for d in API_CONSUMERS if d['host'] == host][-1]
```

Or just keep the entire list. (An exception will still be raised if the list is empty).

Comment: This is subtly but importantly different than what his code does.  His code will get the last consumer for which the host matches the target host, where yours will get the first.  He'd probably be better off just getting the generator you create and iterating over that as he needs.

Comment: True, but I think we both work under the assumption of unique hosts. The OP can correct me if I'm wrong about that.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't accept both answers - I accepted the other because he answered first.

Answer (score 0):

A (perhaps) more python construct would be to use for-else:

```
for consumer_info in API_CONSUMERS:
    if consumer_info['host'] == host:
        consumer = consumer_info
        #do stuff with consumer
        break
else:
    #clause if no consumer
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have the most efficient search process, you should use **dictionary** data structure.because it's complexity(order of growth) is the least.you can do it this way:

```
API_CONSUMERS = {'127.0.0.1:5000':{'name':'localhost','api_key': 'Ahth2ea5Ohngoop5'},
                 '127.0.0.1:5001': {'name':'localhost2','api_key': 'Ahth2ea5Ohngoop6'}}
```

and if  you wanted to search use:

```
if host in API_CONSUMERS.keys():
    return API_CONSUMERS[host]['api_key']
```